# debian Tesseract TESSDATA_PREFIX issue

Tags: debian, tesseract

I'm currently running an error with my Python program using Tesseract. For now I do my test on Ubuntu and I have no problem (Tesseract v4 is on the official repo). I want now to try it under Debian and because official repo doesn't have the v4 of Tesseract, I have to compile from source Tesseract. I do it like this  :

```
git clone -b4.0.0 https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract
cd tesseract
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. && make
make install
```

Then I do this :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib  
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/
```

My tessdata prefix contain all the trained language but I have the following error :

> pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file ./fra.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'fra\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')

I try to put the TESSDATA_PREFIX onto the ~/.profile, add it to the PATH var in the same file, but I still have the issue

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think you missed the final `tessdata` on TESSDATA directory (as the error message is telling you).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I did a fair bit of looking around and then realised that the problem was actually rather simple and the answer was right there - the error message is explicit about where the files are expected to be, in the parent folder of tessdata.

*Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the **parent directory** of your "tessdata" directory*

By copying the language files and the training data (in my case eng.traineddata and osd.traineddata) in the tessdata folder /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata to the parent folder one level up.

It seems a configuration file expects files to be one level up so /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/

These were the correct locations in my case for an Ubuntu installation